# Jquery not loading inside iFrame that includes jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have to dynamically create an Iframe and fill it with content, so I am doing the following:

```
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.id = 'myIframe';
document.getElementById('myIframe').contentWindow.document.write(myIframeContent);
```

The issue is that the iframe content relies on jquery. Jquery is included in the head of myIframeContent like so:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

However using jquery selectors (e.g. $('#myDiv')) in the iframe results in the variable being undefined. I assume because there is a problem loading jquery, but I'm not sure why. Is it due to how the iframe is being created? Other scripts included in the iframe content are working correctly.

Comment: Why do you need to use an iFrame? Very little cannot be done in a div. For example I only use iFrame if my CSS breaks a widget included from somewhere else

Comment: If jQuery wasn’t embedded, then `$('#myDiv')` should give you an error message in the browser console saying that `$` is not defined.

Comment: @CBroe Yes that's the error message I am getting.

Comment: @mplungjan Using an iframe is a requirement

Comment: Well, so is presenting a _proper_ [mre] when asking about such problems here ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just need to escape the `<script><\/script>`

SO cannot run this due to security errors

```js
var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
ifrm.id = 'myIframe';
const myIframeContent = `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"><\/script>
<div id="myDiv">Hello</div>
<script>$("#myDiv").html("Hello there")<\/script>`;
document.getElementById("content").appendChild(ifrm);
document.getElementById("myIframe").contentWindow.document.write(myIframeContent);
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```